# Oracle APEX Interactive Grid toolbar customization

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have an Interactive Grid on my page and I want to add a button to a toolbar. I have wrote a javascript function and tried to add the code under Advanced->Javascript. But when I did that my grid content disappeared completely, only heading was left. Is that the wrong place to add my code? How to ensure the function gets called?

Below is my function:

```
function(config) {
    var $ = apex.jQuery,
    toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar(),
    toolbarGroup = toolbarData.toolbarFind("actions3"); // group where Add Row button is

    toolbarGroup.controls.push({type: "BUTTON",
                            action: "selection-delete"
                           });

    config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
    return config;
}
```

Comment: Could you check if is there any error on console? I try this code here and works.

Comment: I replicate this problem on a master detail interactive grid. If I put this code only on detail, the grid report disappeared, if put on both, works. i do not know why this happen.

Comment: @romeuBraga, I am new to APEX. How do i check the  console?

Comment: On chrome, F12 >> console.

Comment: thank you! got an error " toolbarData.toolbarFind not a function"

Comment: Yes, this is the same error here when i put this code on a detail of interactive grid. If i put on both, master and detail, works. But, I do not know how solve this.

Comment: Please add your last comment as an answer so I could accept it. It helped me solve my issue

Comment: Thanks Elena, did you do anything else?

Comment: No, for that particular issue that was enough. The interesting thing is that in another application I had a master detail page and the master did not have any javascript code and it still worked for the IG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why, but this problem occurs when you use this code in a detail of an interactive grid.

The problem is solved when you put the code in both the reports, the master and the detail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function "toolbarFind" is deprecated or just removed in current version. Try:

`toolbarGroup = toolbarData[toolbarData.length-2];`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be preferable if you would edit your answer to correct it instead of posting a correction as a comment.